# "Being ran", "being runned" or something else?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, tenses

The past tense of *run* is *ran*. However, you couldn't say something was being "ran" poorly i.e. the business was ran poorly. However, saying "runned" would be wrong as well. What would be the word to use in this instance:

> **The government will be prevented from being **_*__*_** properly**.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [passive voice in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice) uses the [past participle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_participle), not the simple past.

- Sing-sang-sung. *Song being sung*.
- Ring-rang-rung. *Bell being rung*.
- Do-did-done. *Deeds being done.*
- Speak-spoke-spoken. *Word being spoken*.
- Break-broke-broken. *Rules being broken*.
- Run-ran-run. *Government being run.*

(Your confusion probably stems from the fact that for many verbs, the past participle and the simple past are identical, as in make-made-made, play-played-played, etc.)

Comment: Note that [some speakers, especially speakers of AAVE](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1263), might find  _the business was ran poorly_, _deeds being did_, _government being ran_, etc. to be grammatical.

Comment: Yes, in fact we now have [a dedicated tag](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sp-as-pp) for questions dealing with that construction.

Answer (score 5):

The missing word is run. The government will be prevented from being run properly.

Not that prevention will be necessary - it will fail to run properly all by itself. Governments always do.

Answer (score -4):

You want to use the present tense for the word **ran** in the following sentence without using **runned**.

The government will be prevented from being **runned** properly.

I would say that you could use **managed** or **maintained**.

So it will look like this

The government will be prevented from being **managed** properly.

or this

The government will be prevented from being **maintained** properly.

Comment: It is more idiomatic to say: **to run a government**, as if it were a real business, than saying **to manage a gov't.**

Comment: Present tense? Say what?